# How to make a clickable image float in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert some pictures in my website which "float" in the page... even while I scroll my page.

So with the following code I can make an object float on my website... but how do I make an image float which also acts like an hyperlink?

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; left: 0px">  </div>
<a href="www.google.com"> <img src="pic.jpg" height: 32px; width:32px;> </img> </a>
```

But how do I merge them both?

Comment: Just move the anchor element into the div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Terry sayd in the comment you can just move the code up in the div. Cause the link will ned something which has a position set. Which is the case with your div.

Also, the `<img>` tag is a self closing tag. So `</img>` will not be needed. Also if you write `height` and or `width` directly on the `<img>` tag it has to be

```
<img src="your/src.url.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

and not

```
<img src="your/src.url.jpg" width:100px; height:100px; />
```

this will not work!

So here your working example.

```css
img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; left: 0px">
   <a href="www.google.com">
         <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/adirondacks-sun-beams-640x300.jpg" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need keep the anchor tag inside the div. And also while specifying the height and width of the image you should use quotes like `width="25px"` or use css style.

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; left: 0px"> 
    <a href="http://www.google.com"> <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-image-128.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"/> </a>
</div>
```